# Ubuntu 14.04: Problems with nivida driver for Geforce GTX 965M

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness

Sorry for my bad English. I'm from Bremen, Germany. I also have some Problems with my Schenker Laptop W705 with nvidia GeForce GTX 965M. My Ubuntu version is 14.04.4. I have installed the property nvidia Driver 352.63 via "additional drivers" dialog.

My problems are: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> shows black screens. Return to GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> work. My brightness settings work, but they will not be saved (after reboot) temporally Keyboard and Touchpad stop working (Probably another problem)

Any ideas? Thank you for reading.

Best regards Michael Flathmann

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a kernel boot parameter `reboot=pci` to the Grub configuration. This solved the problem in my case.

To do this you need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and modify the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to include `reboot=pci` so afterwards you have for example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=pci"
```

After changing the file, run `sudo update-grub` then reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But its to late.

Comment: Sorry for my editing..

Comment: I gave up (inclusive changing the boot parameter) , Now I use Xubuntu on an old Dell Laptop with chipset graphics. It works fine. For my python programming just right.